# cannot find module @chainlink/contracts

Tags: blockchain, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

i'm trying to use a chainlink contract to get the price feed for price conversion from eth to usd so i installed @chainlink/contracts but i'm getting error

```
Error: Cannot find module '@chainlink/contracts'
```

here are my two solidity contracts

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

library PriceConverter {
    function convertEthToUsd(
        uint256 amount,
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed
    ) internal view returns (uint256) {
        (, int price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(price * amount);
    }
}
```

and

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "./libraries/PriceConverter.sol";

contract Pthc {
    using PriceConverter for uint256;
    address public immutable i_owner;
    uint256 public amount;
    address public currentWinner;
    string public imageURL;
    AggregatorV3Interface immutable i_priceFeed;
    Error Pthc_NotEnaughSentError;
    modifier OnlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == i_owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor(address priceFeedAddress) {
        i_owner = msg.sender;
        i_priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeedAddress);
    }

    function pay(string calldata _imageURL) public {
        require(
            msg.value.convertEthToUsd(i_priceFeed) > 2,
            Pthc_NotEnaughSentError
        );
        if (msg.value > amount) {
            amount = msg.value;
            currentWinner = msg.sender;
            imageURL = _imageURL;
        }
    }

    function withdraw() public payable OnlyOwner {
        (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{
            value: address(this).balance
        }("");
    }
}
```

i uninstalled it and installed it again but i'm still getting the same error